# The function $f:[-2,3]\to R $ given by $f(x)=x^3$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The function $f:[-2,3]\to R $ given by $f(x)=x^3$ is

1. One to one
2. Onto
3. Into
4. Both 1 and 3.

My work :

I guess $f:[-2,3]\to R $ means the set of domain is ${-2,-1,0,1,2,3}$. Then how to complete the rest?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. That's not the domain. The interval $[-2,3]$ contains many more points than just the six points that you listed.

Comment: @zipirovich,  could you please elaborate on what does it mean?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler What does it mean for a function to be "***into***"?

Comment: @dxiv, Function f from set A to set B is Into function if at least set B has a element which is not connected with any of the element of set A.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler That would be more commonly called "*not* surjective". As to the question, one hint is that $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing.

Comment: It means exactly what I said. For example, $1.5$ is also in this interval. And so is $-0.123456789$. And so are infinitely many other numbers.

Comment: No. f:[-2,3]->R means that the domain is every real number between -2,3 inclusive.  Every number.  2.775643678 is in the domain.  So is -$\sqrt {2} $.  So is 2.775636781.  Every number.  One to one means that f (x)$\ne $f (y) if $x\ne y $.  Is that true.  Onto means for every y in R there is an x in [-2,3] where f (x)=y.  Is that true?  If f (x)=64 what is x? Is it in [-3,2].  Into.  That's not commonly used.  What does the book say it means.

Comment: I've never heard of into used that way.  But okay.  *IS* this function into?  What prevents you from being able to answer this question?

Comment: @fleablood,  the answer in book is 1

Comment: Um, why are you telling me the answer in the book is 1?  Did I ask?

Comment: @fleablood,  for one to one $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$